# Pytest: Using fixtures in setup_method

Tags: python, pytest

Following this pattern: https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/xunit_setup.html

How do I use/inject `fixture_foo` into `setup_method`

```
class TestClassX:
    def setup_method(self, method):
        # I need `fixture_foo` here

    def teardown_method(self, method):
        # N/A

    def test_cool(self, fixture_foo):
        # Why can `fixture_foo` be injected here and not in `setup_method`?
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You'd have to switch to the `pytest`-style fixturing to access fixtures.  An equivalent of the `setup_method` can be achieved as follows:

```
@pytest.fixture
def f():
    return 'ohai'


class Test:
    @pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
    def setup_method_fixture(self, request, f):
        self.f = f
        self.method_name = request.function.__name__

    def test(self):
        assert self.method_name == 'test'
        assert self.f == 'ohai'
```

This `autouse` fixture will get called once per test method inside the class

Comment: "You'd have to switch to the `pytest`-style fixturing to access fixtures". Can you give an example of this style accessing the fixture inside a test class?

Comment: @Keto the code block in my answer

Comment: Thanks, I had misunderstood your answer thinking the example was a hybrid of xunit and pytest.